# Beautiful Soup Questions

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to scrap the following website, however, I have encountered some problems. As you can see, I am not really familiar with regex and I hope you can give me some pointers to how to solve this problem.

Basically, I hope I can download all the transaction data into the database. However, I need to retrieve it first.

Thank you

Below is my quote:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://bochk.etnet.com.hk/content/bochkweb/eng/quote_transaction_daily_history.php?services=STK&code=6881\
    &ip=boc.etnet.com.hk&host=BochkUMSContent&sessionId=44c99b61679e019666f0570db51ad932'
pattern = re.compile('var json_result = (.*?);')

def turnover_detail(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    data = soup.find_all("script")
    for json in data:
        print(json)

turnover_detail(url)
```

Comment: what problems have you encountered?

Comment: Unable to retrieve the whole day transaction....Thank you